# How to compare multiple csv files with millions of records?

Tags: bigdata, database-migration

I was provided with two sets of csv files that in theory should be the same, but for some reason one of the sets contains more data than the other (the csv. files are automatic weekly data backups from a crm system).

Ideally, I'd simply open the csv files and do a vlookup and find the missing rows (or the "extra" rows)and start investigating where they come from and why the discrepancy.

However, these files are huge, and contains millions of rows. Any idea how can you compare the files and find out how they are different? What applications (hopefully free and easy to use) can you recommend? I'm not able to open the files because I'm hitting Excel's row limit.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: kdiff3  http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using UltraEdit and UltraCompare. UltraCompare's ability to compare files is amazing. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can always open big files using lite editors like vi, nano etc.

Its extreme option but I love awk for these things so, you can use awk to compare two files or more.

```
Example:

       awk '
            FNR==NR {
                    # file one use a key that need to match with file 2
                    from_file_one[$1] = $1
                    next
            }
            {
                    # file two check if file's two key has not matched with
                    # some of the keys in file one 
                    if(!($1 in hour)) {
                           print $1 "didn't match"
                    }
            } file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could import them into SQL server (or similar program) and use SQL (or similar language) to compare them.

This might not be the most eloquent option but sometimes the straightest path is through the mud.